# Angular 4 router child path not found (outlet)

Tags: angular, angular-router, router-outlet

I have some issues with Angular 4 router and components. What i'm trying to do. I have a view (SuperUser) which contains 2 oulets (side menu and content).

In router i have Super user with 2 children (sidemenu and content), with it's own router but i'm getting **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'superuser/contexts'** on *http://localhost:4200/superuser/contexts* uri. Source bellow.

**App.Router**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: "superuser",
    component: SuperuserComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: "",
        component: SideMenuComponent,
        outlet: 'superuser-sidemenu'
      },
      {
        path: "contexts",
        component: ContextsComponent,
        outlet: 'superuser-content'
      }

    ]
  },

  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
]
```

**SuperUserComponent.html**

```
<div class="py-5 public-area-body-background">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="superuser-sidemenu">
            <router-outlet name="superuser-sidemenu"></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div id="superuser-content">
            <router-outlet name="superuser-content"></router-outlet>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SideMenuComponent.html**

```
<div class="card text-white p-5 bg-light shadow sidemenu">
    <div class="card-body sidemenu">
      <h4 class="mb-4 text-dark" >Main Menu</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04">
              <option selected>Context...</option>
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
              <option value="3">Three</option>
            </select> 
        </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

**ContextsComponent.html**

```
<div class="card text-white p-5 bg-light shadow">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>Content here</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should reread the guide to auxiliary routes here : https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-routes . When using named outlet your url sould be like http://.../superuser(superuser-content:contexts)

Comment: Sorry, i don't really get it.

Comment: did you read the documentation I linked in the precedent comment?

Comment: took 5 more looks on it and managed to make it works, thanks to your link. Can be Posted as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are realing components with children outlets, it is good to make that as a module. In your case you can create to more files say super-user.module.ts and super-user-routing.module.ts.

Hope you are declared all these components in your app.module.ts. This is not a good practice, in future your app become slower. So remove the declarations of *SuperUserComponent, SideMenuComponent, and ContextsComponent* from app.module and declare them in new **super-user.module.ts** file. Plus you can create a new component inside superUser and to display the content of your current SuperUserComponent.html, and SuperUserComponent.html file should only contain a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Change the code of app.router as

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'superuser',
    loadChildren: './super-user/super-user.module#SuperUserModule'      
  },    
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

And finally super-user-routing.module.ts as

```
export const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: SuperUserComponet,
        children: [ { path: 'view', component: ListComponent},
        path: 'context', component: ContextSComponent},    
      ...]
    ]
```

Now you can access these components from any where as `routerLink="/superuser/context"` and so on.
To see the current view of super-user.component.html you need to use `routerLink="/superuser/list"`

Comment: still getting 404

Comment: your solution combined with Pierre's comment (documentation) worked thanks

Comment: Glad to know it